# Python self-update from git

Tags: python, git, pygame, auto-update, self-updating

I'm developing a game in Python, and I would like to implement a system where the user could select if they want to receive auto-updates from git, and if they do, if they want to update from the "stable" branch or the "beta" branch.

Is there a simple way to do this, such as a library to allow python to access git? I'd like to avoid having to set up a web host that can send the files over ftp when I have a git repository that already holds all of the code I need. I would prefer a way that doesn't require the user to have git installed outside of the game, but if I have to require git to allow updates I am okay with it.

If it helps, we can assume that the game's updater is self-contained and will never need to update itself.

Answer (score 3):

`pip` can install from `git` directly (you can choose a branch, tag if you want). `pip` is bundled with recent Python versions (2.7.9+, 3.4+).

- update your program e.g.:

  ```
  subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-U',
          'git+...uri...#egg=your_package'])
  ```
- restart it:

  ```
  os.execv(sys.executable, sys.argv + ['--updated'])
  ```

Beware: it is very simplistic. Review how other programs with similar requirments do it.